# Unit testing a lambda function in Java

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a lambda function written like this:

```
@Bean
    public Function<Request, Audience>
    fromAudienceDTOToAudienceMapper(
            final Function<ExpressionDto, Expression> fromExpressionDtoToExpression,
            final Function<SchemaDto, Schema> fromSchemaDtoToSchema,
            final Function<PolicyDTO, Policy>
                    fromDataGovernancePolicyDtoToDataGovernancePolicy
            )
```

As this is a bean and a lambda function, I am unable to come up with a way using Junit/Mockito to actually test this out. If I instantiate the function, it will have its own apply() and then the original code will not get called.
I'm inclining towards converting this to a class itself, but thought of finding a way to unit test this out directly. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you combined a `UnaryOperator<ExpressionDto>`, the `Function<ExpressionDto, Expression>`, and another `UnaryOperator<ExpressionDto>`, then that would be equivalent to the first field's `Function<ExpressionDto, Expression>`. Using a similar approach for the other fields, you can then assess the "before" and "after" of the lambda call, provided you don't modify the results yourself.

Comment: In general, instead of writing this as `public Function<Request, Audience>`, you should usually write `public Audience fromAudienceDTO..(..., Request request)` and use a lambda at the call site.  Using Mockito is probably even a worse idea.

Comment: Hi Louis, so what you are suggesting is to use strongly typed object instead of function?

Comment: @duffymo you know that a "lambda function" has nothing to do with "AWS lambda", right? right? ;) A lambda function is executed locally and in-memory and there's virtually no extra latency compared to a regular function call.

Comment: My mistake.  The term is overloaded.  You are correct.